# How to run multiline Python statement in VSCode without needing to select it all?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to be able to run the entirety of a multiline statement like this

```
dtypes = {
    'date' : 'str',
    'item_code' : 'category',
    'branch_code' : 'category',
    'sale_qty' : 'float',
    'sale_val' : 'float',
    'return_qty' : 'float',
    'return_val' : 'float'
}
```

by having the cursor on the first line and pressing a shortcut.

I currently have the command `jupyter.execSelectionInteractive` bound to `ctrl+enter`, however that only executes either the current line if nothing is selected or the selection.
So in a statement like the one mentioned above, it would attempt to run `dtypes = {` only and fail with an error and I would need to manually select the whole statement to execute it.

This is a built in function in many IDEs like RStudio where if you press the shortcut for running the current line, it intelligently knows that the current line is part of a multiline statement and runs the whole statement.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in VSCode?

I also already know that I can use the comment `#%%` to create Jupyter cells that I can run at once, but I don't want to have to insert `#%%` at every single multiline statement so I can execute it easily without selecting it all.

Comment: I have submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18105) on GitHub.